# Can't use at_step in squid config

Tags: proxy, squid, telegram

I'm trying to configure Squid to work as a Telegram Messenger proxy using [this guide](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Chat/Telegram). My Squid complains about their proposed config options (output of `squid -k parse`):

```
2019/05/22 11:17:20| Processing: acl DiscoverSNIHost at_step SslBump1
2019/05/22 11:17:20| FATAL: Invalid ACL type 'at_step'
FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 1003: acl DiscoverSNIHost at_step SslBump1
Squid Cache (Version 3.5.27): Terminated abnormally.
```

Squid website says that `at_step` appeared in version 3.5, so the version shouldn't be an issue. Some forums suggest compiling Squid from source code with flags like `--with-openssl` and `--enable-ssl-crtd` to make options like `at_step` working. I wonder is this could be the problem. And should I, then, compile and install Squid myself?

Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: If you are trying to use proxy with Telegram you just can activate proxy in Telegram advanced settings.

Comment: I don't see such an option on my phone, but at this point, I'd like to figure out Squid. In the meantime, I put on dante socks proxy server. It worked out of the box.

Comment: Settings / Data & Storage / Proxy

Comment: I can't see what you're suggesting. I need an actual proxy server (e.g. squid) up, and only then I can put its address / port into "Settings / Data & Storage / Proxy".

Comment: @JoKeR without a proxy you can't just enable telegram's proxy function. Your comment is off-topic and is false information

Comment: maybe you have to build squid with the ssl module